# How do I change directory to the systemroot directory of the current main operating system via DOS?

Tags: windows, command, dos, cd

The title is pretty much self explanatory but I only want a simple CD (or CHDIR) dos command that will take me to the root directory of the current running operating system.

I make :

```
CD %windir%
CD ..
```

But I'm quite sure there is 1 simple command to execute this in more convenient way.

Thanks all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
CD %SystemDrive%
```

or

```
CD %HOMEDRIVE%
```

UPDATE:

This will do the trick:

```
cd /D %SystemDrive%\
```

You can read the /D documentation if you execute "cd /?"

Comment: @Steven please note the backslash at the end of the command. It will not work if you exclude it.

Comment: Yep! Backslash at the end was the small issue :) Working like a charm! Many Thanks !!!